# How to cumulative sum with balance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-query-language

I am trying to achieve cumulative sum of cash balance
Trying to make

| ---ID--- | - Date--- | Transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01/03 | 5 |
| 123456 | 01/03 | -0.3 |
| 123456 | 01/03 | 0 |

into

| ---ID--- | - Date--- | Transaction | BalanceBefore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01/03 | 5 | 0 |
| 123456 | 01/03 | -0.3 | 5 |
| 123456 | 01/03 | 0 | 4.7 |

Tried

```
SELECT ID,
 Date,
 Transaction,
SUM(Transaction) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS BalanceBefore
FROM TABLE
where ID='123456'
order by Date
```

With no success
as
[My wrong results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvPgr.png)

As you can see I can't understand how to start with 0 balance for the first row.

Of course there are many IDs with more dates, the partition in the end should be by date and ID.

Comment: What constitutes "with no success", and how are you suppose order transactions, if they have same id and date?

Answer (score 0):

You almost done it right. But since you need value before transaction, you don't need to add value of current row to sum. Easiest way - is to use `sum() Over (...)` (as you did), and then subtract value of current row.

```sql
SELECT ID,
 Date_,
 Transaction_,
SUM(Transaction_) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date_) - Transaction_ AS BalanceBefore
FROM t1
-- where ID='123456'
order by ID, Date_
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4wwHTUa9).

I've also added `PARTITION BY ID` to your sum, just in case if you'll need to get list for more then one `ID` in one query.